# Do exponentials in semigroups only have formal meaning?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $L$ be a linear differential operator and consider the PDE
$$\begin{cases} u_t + Lu = 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n\\
u = f, \quad t = 0\end{cases} \tag{1}$$
It is known that we may construct a continuous semigroup $S(t)$ whose infinitesimal generator is $-L$, and thus for all $t > 0$, $u(t) = S(t)f$ for sufficiently nice $f$.

What I am confused about is how one arrives at the often seen expression $S(t) = e^{Lt}$. For example, on its own it is not clear what it means to apply $e^{Lt}$ to a function $f$, and it seems what is actually meant is to apply $S(t)$ to $f$.

I know that this is inspired by the fact that in (1) we replace $L$ by a constant matrix $A$, then the resulting ODE has a solution $e^{-At}$. I also know that some meaning can be given to the exponential of a matrix either by an infinite series (if $A$ is bounded) or by using the functional calculus (if $A$ is self-adjoint).

However in neither of these two cases do I see why $S(t) = e^{Lt}$. Is there any justification for this or is this only a formal expression/a definition? In other words, do we *define* $e^{Lt}$ as "the semigroup whose infinitesimal generator is $L$" and the exponential has no further meaning here?

Comment: There are ways that the exponential arises in a slightly more rigorous way than just by analogy with the finite dimensional case. For example when $L$ is a differential operator, by taking the Fourier transform we see that $\hat{u}_t(t,\xi) = -P_L(\xi)\hat{u}(t,\xi)$ where $P_L$ is some polynomial, so we get $\hat{u}(t,\xi) = e^{-tP_L(\xi)} \hat{f}(\xi)$ as a solution, and $e^{-tL}$ acts via convolution with the Fourier inverse of $e^{-tP_L(\xi)}$. There’s also an interpretation of $e^{-tL}$ as a limit of backwards Euler approximations that requires more space than a comment.

Comment: @kieransquared We also have the semigroup property $S(t + s) = S(t)S(s)$ which is also an exponential property. I suppose all this further justifies the notation $e^{-Lt}$, but is the actual meaning of it as an exponential still only formal?

Comment: To elaborate on the backwards Euler point: Formally, by applying n backwards Euler steps, we’d expect $(I-(t/n)L)^{-n}f$ to converge to $u(t)$ as $n\to\infty$. These ideas can be made rigorous using the resolvent operator; see Bressan’s Lecture Notes in Functional Analysis for example. For the most part however, the analogy to exponentials is mostly formal for unbounded operators (but can be made rigorous for bounded operators, and extending via some kind of approximation argument).

Comment: @kieransquared Thank you, I will check out that reference. For bounded operators I suppose the approach is to use the Taylor series for $e$? If so, it is strange and unintuitive to me that the resulting series when used with the Laplacian would solve the heat equation. For example, wouldn't this require the initial condition to be $C^\infty$ since we will have derivatives of arbitrary order in the series, whereas the existence theorem for the heat equation only requires the initial condition to be $C^0$?

Comment: This is partly why the series definition of $\exp$ doesn’t really work for unbounded operators. In the case of the heat equation though, $e^{-t\Delta}$ formally has some cancellations in its Taylor series, which is why you’d expect that it smooths things out (again, this is purely formal). In contrast $e^{t\Delta}$ does not define a nice, well posed semigroup.

Comment: @kieransquared I understand now, I will take it as a definition motivated by the exponential but nothing more. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: It depends on your definition of exponential ... but the first definition of the exponential for me was the solution $\exp'=\exp$ with value $1$ at $0$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time evolution has an exponential type of property. For example, suppose you have a state vector $x_1$ at $t=t_1$, and you want to know what the state vector will evolve to become at some $t_2 > t_1$. Then you can symbolically write
$$
           x_2 = S(t_2,t_1)x_1
$$
This assumes, of course, that $x_2$ is unique, which would be the case for any well-defined time evolution problem. You can see that there must be an exponential type of description because
$$
          x_3=S(t_3,t_2)S(t_2,t_1)x_1,
$$
which implies that
$$
              S(t_3,t_2)S(t_2,t_1)=S(t_3,t_1).
$$
If the system $S$ is time-independent, then $S$ will depend only on the differences of the two arguments, which leads to a time-invariant formulation where $S(t'',t')=\mathscr{S}(t''-t')$, meaning that the evolution depends only on the difference between the two arguments, and not the arguments themselves. The end result is a simple exponential property:
$$
        \mathscr{S}(t_b)\mathscr{S}(t_a)=\mathscr{S}(t_b+t_a).
$$
In other words, time evolution has a simple exponential property when the system itself does not depend on time. As you might expect, in this case, to be able to write
$$
     \mathscr{S}(t)=e^{tA}.
$$
With suitable continuity in $t$, such a representation is generally possible for linear systems.

Comment: Thank you. So the exponential symbol is used for semigroups because they satisfy the exponential property and nothing more? Is it by chance that $\mathscr{S}(t)$ coincides with the the functional calculus for $A$ and the function $\exp$ or is this a consequence of it satisfying the exponential property?

Comment: @CBBAM : The generator $A$ of a semigroup does not have to self-adjoint, normal, etc. So it's hard to define a functional calculus for $A$ in a straightforward manner. However, you can define a functional calculus using a Laplace transform formalism through the exponential form.

Comment: I see, so if there is no functional calculus available for an operator $A$ then the only reason we call it the exponential map is because it satisfies the exponential property?